# ng-select2 insertAdjacentHTML

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect

How can I insert ng-select2 into my html via insertAdjacentHTML when I click the button?
When I try to do this, it shows Empty.
Or is there any other better way?

thanks

```
this.k++;
    var str = "";
    str += "<div class=\"row\">";
    str += "<div class=\"col-md-3\"> ";
    str += "  <div class=\"form-group\"> ";
    str += "<ng-select2 [data]=\"s2Locations_List[" + this.k + "]\" [width]=\"'100%'\"  ";
    str += "  (valueChanged)=\"onChange_Locations($event," + this.k + ")\" class=\"select2\">";
    str += "</ng-select2> ";
    str += "  </div>";
    str += "</div> ";

    str += " </div>   ";

    this.locationAreaList.nativeElement.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', str);
    this.ddlLocations(this.k);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you don't append html code in this way.

It's better create a component for rendering your dynamic code and load it when you click the button using [Dynamic component loader](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader).

Another alternative would be to use content projection to create flexible, reusable components. In this case take a look to [conditional content projection](https://angular.io/guide/content-projection#conditional).